# List of Tasks is not updating - Flutter

Tags: flutter

I've saw a code snippet for my app that i wanted to use.. my problem now is that when i'm typing a new task into the app, my app just won't show that to the screen until a hot reload of the app. But first the user can't do any hot reloads AND for user experience it's very bad. If you need more code or debug things, please ask in the comments!

Here is the code (Ig it's this part thats not updating):

tasks_list.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:learnon/screens/tasksscreennew.dart';
import 'package:learnon/widgets/task_tile.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:learnon/models/tasks_data.dart';
import 'dart:core';

class TasksList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<TasksList> createState() => _TasksListState();
}

class _TasksListState extends State<TasksList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<TaskData>(
      builder: (context, taskData, child) {
        return ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return TaskTile(
              taskTitle: taskData.tasks[index].name,
              isChecked: taskData.tasks[index].isDone,
              timeLeft: taskData.tasks[index].date!
                          .difference(DateTime.now())
                          .inMinutes >
                      0
                  ? ('${taskData.tasks[index].date!.difference(DateTime.now()).inHours.toString()} Hours left')
                  : 'Time Expired',
              checkboxCallback: (checkBoxState) {
                taskData.updateTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
              },
              longPressCallback: () {
                if ((taskData.tasks[index].id!) != 0 ||
                    (taskData.tasks[index].id!) != 1) {
                  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                      .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id!);
                  flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                      .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id! + 1);
                }
                taskData.deleteTask(taskData.tasks[index]);
              },
              notificationCallback: () {
                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                    .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id!);
                flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
                    .cancel(taskData.tasks[index].id! + 1);
              },
            );
          },
          itemCount: taskData.taskCount,
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

simple wrap your tasks list in an streamBuilder:

```
StreamBuilder(
  // anytime the snapshot changes it builds the builder again
  stream: tasks_snapshot,
  builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {

    return TaskList;
  },
);
```